# display: inline-flex; causes weird box model rendering

Tags: html, css, less, flexbox

i encountered something wierd recently and i wan't to share it with you and maybe someone knows why this is happening.

Because i have not enough rep i need to link the screenshots:

**Even - No Spacing**

[image]

---

**Odd - Spacing**

[image]

As you can see, there is no margin, padding or some other spacing definition and the browser knows that. But still there is this wierd spacing and i do absolutely not know why.

Less:

```
@grd-height  : 110px;
@grd-width   : @grd-height;
@grd-per-line: 4;

.grd {

    width: (@grd-width * @grd-per-line) + 15%;

    .data {

        display: inline-flex;
        height: @grd-height;
        width: @grd-width;
        padding: 0px;

    }
    .data:nth-child(even) {
        background: #eee;   
    }

}
```

(i put the 15% in there to fix this for my testings)

HTML:

```
    <body>

        <section class='grd'>
            <section class='data'>hello world</section>
            <section class='data'>what</section>
            <section class='data'>are </section>
            <section class='data'>you doing</section>
            <section class='data'>hello world</section>
            <section class='data'>what</section>
            <section class='data'>are </section>
            <section class='data'>you doing</section>
            <section class='data'>hello world</section>
            <section class='data'>what</section>
            <section class='data'>are </section>
            <section class='data'>you doing</section>
            <section class='data'>hello world</section>
            <section class='data'>what</section>
            <section class='data'>are </section>
            <section class='data'>you doing</section>
        </section>

    </body>
```

Last note: I compile the less code with Prepros App.

Comment: It's not the odd ones. If you add a background colour you'll see they're right up to the edge. It's the actual `section` adding a margin.

Comment: no it's obv not the case, i tried it with different elements and nothing changed actualy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's the `white space` in your HTML document which is adding a `4px` offset there because you are using `display: inline-flex;`... I just kept all the tags inline and see now how it behaves

Also there are numerous ways to get rid of the white space, either you can use `font-size: 0;` on the parent element, and set the `font-size` back on child element or you can also use HTML empty comments like `</section><!-- --><section>`

<s>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2FmNP/1/)</s> *(Buggy demo)*

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/2FmNP/)

---

Also, it's worth mentioning here that you need to set your `width` to `115px` else you will get a chess board layout, as you just saved `5px` of white space in each of the element.

Comment: I know, thats why i added the +15% width.
====
i totaly can agree with the obstacle of white spaces, already thought about it but did not debug it. But it is not only with display: inline-flex, it doesn't matter if i use inline-flex, inline-block or inline-table all of them (obviously). I only wanted to mention this because a moderator changed the topic to not that likely one.

Comment: @ununseptium yes, they all leave white space, and hence inorder to get rid of them, I've provided you some standard solutions, pick one, you like :)

Comment: yeah i already accepted your answer, setting up the font size works well for me, thanks.